# PHPMailer Laravel attachment from form not working

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

i'm trying to add a PDF attachment in my PHPmailer but it won't send the attachment.

**Controller:**

```
        $recipient = Request::input('emailaddress');
        $recipientName = Request::input('name');
        $file = Request::input('file');

     $mail = new \PHPMailer(true); 
        try {
            $mail->isSMTP(); 
            $mail->CharSet = "utf-8"; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
            $mail->Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
            $mail->Port = 587; 
            $mail->Username = "username";
            $mail->Password = "password";
            $mail->setFrom("info@email.nl", "Business");
            $mail->Subject = "Offerte";
            $mail->MsgHTML("Test.");
            $mail->addAddress($recipient, $recipientName);

            if (isset($_FILES[$file]) &&
                $_FILES[$file]['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'],
                $_FILES[$file]['name']);
            }

            $mail->send();
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            dd($e);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
       }
       return back()->with('send', 'send');    
}
```

**The form:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/offer/sendmail">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Aan:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{$offers->name}}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="emailaddress">Email-adres:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" value="{{$offers->email}}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subject">Onderwerp:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subject">Bericht:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subject">Voeg een bestand toe:</label>
          <input type ="file" name='file' id='uploaded_file'>
        </div>



      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Verzenden</button>

        </form>
```

It does send the email but there is no attachment in it. Do you have any idea why? I've also changed $mail->username and password so i can keep my credentials private.

Comment: Could you debug the values of `isset($_FILES[$file])` &
`$_FILES[$file]['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OKÉ`, clearly one of these is false and we need to check which one it is.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question as i'm kinda new to PHP. How do i debug? Just a dd?

Comment: That could be a way, you could also use `Log::info($value)` to write to your log (after importing the correct facade) or use `dump()` or simply echo the values

Comment: I've used dump($_FILES) and it just gives me an empty object [ ]

Comment: When i do dump($FILES[$file]); it gives me: undefined index of: blank

Answer (score 0):

This code is unsafe; you're trusting values from `$_FILES`. You need to call `is_uploaded_file` or `move_uploaded_file`. [Read the PHP docs on handling uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004).

On a more basic level, you have not set the `enctype` attribute on the form, so file elements will not work - you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, so your `form` tag will become.

```
<form method="POST" action="/offer/sendmail" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It's a good idea to set a `MAX_FILE_SIZE` element too.

Base your code on the [send_file_upload](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) example provided with PHPMailer, which handles uploads correctly and safely.